# Model with many has_one associations very slow on deleting records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Notification` model. Any time certain actions like `Comment`, `Like`, `Mention`, `Follow` happens this table gets a single record added to it. This table is now many millions of records long. The only index I have on it is on the user_id - which has been important as I show notifications to the `current_user`.

On each of these related models, I included the following line

```
  has_one :notification, dependent: :destroy
```

The issue is that all these actions are reversible, so whenever someone, say, unlikes, I need to destroy the related Notification.

As such Notification#destroy action is very slow now, often taking >10secs! I'm certain this is because each time a destroy happens, it has to look up foreign keys like `like_id`, `comment_id`, or `mention_id`

I can add indexes on all these records, but I'm concerned given how big this table is and how often it gets INSERTS and DELETES. Should I be concerned? Is there a better way to structure this?

Comment: Mental note: `:destroy` runs callbacks, `:delete` does not.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is considering flipping the relationship around, use belongs_to rather than has_one so you rely on only the primary key on that table.

Otherwise, you should really have indices on those; it shouldn't be too much of a burden. You'll get hammered on performance if you don't; it may even be locking the database on those deletes.

Use `SHOW TABLE STATUS` to see index sizes to get an idea of what you might be looking at.